# Strange HTML Table Error

Tags: html, xhtml

I created a Bingo Card using Table in HTML. In the second column if I use the letter `I`, the size of the column automatically reduces and if I use any other letter then size of column comes back to normal. Why its happening so?

Table Image (using `I` in Column 2): http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/18575712.png/

Table Image (using `A` in Column 2): http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/580/11014314.png/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bingo Card</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Bingo Card</h2>
    <table border="1px" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>O</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="square0">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="square5">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square6">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square7">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square8">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square9">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="square10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square12">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square13">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square14">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="square15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square16">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square17">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square18">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square19">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="square20">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square21">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square22">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="square24">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Checked it in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: do you want to get it resolved or u want the exact reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same issue in Chrome when column 2 contains an `A`. If you want to have a guaranteed column width you should explicitly define its size using either the `<colgroup>` tag or a corresponding `width` attribute:

```
<table border="1px" width="50%">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="20%"></col>
    <col width="20%"></col>
    <col width="20%"></col>
    <col width="20%"></col>
    <col width="20%"></col>
 </colgroup>
...
```

or

```
<tr>
  <th style="width:20%">B</th>
  ...
```

The browsers just does not make any guarantee if you do not explicitily define the widths for the different columns.

**UPDATE: From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.4):**

> If an author specifies no width information for a column, a user agent
>   may not be able to incrementally format the table since it must wait
>   for the entire column of data to arrive in order to allot an
>   appropriate width.

Answer (score 1):

You could try change the column width with css...

And I think it's happening because of the letter 'I' is "thin" compared to other letters, but I don't sure about that...

Answer (score 1):

I think each character takes some space the width of i is less than A, to get resolved use a css style 
td{width:20%} this should get resolved

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case, it suffices, for most browsing situations, to set the column widths to the same (20%). However, in general, table cell and column width settings in HTML and CSS are just suggestions and may be overridden by browsers, on the basis of the contents requirements. (You can see this if you use a very narrow browser window width here.)

The way to prevent this is to use “fixed” table layout, e.g.

```
<style>
table { table-layout: fixed; }
th { width: 20%; }
</style>
```

“Fixed” layout has its implications. For example, if the content does not fit, it will get truncated.